# How to update from other table in Oracle's sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

I have two table and I want update table A from Table B in Oracle's sql

```
table A
customer_id    geo_id     geo
1234567890       3521     texas
0987654321       3624     dallas
1597536842       3121     mexicocity
```

```
table B
geo_id        customer_id
8745          1234567890
2145          0987654321
3699          1597536842
```

```
update table A
set   geo_id   = (select geo_id from table B)
where tableA.customer_id = tableB.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MERGE` statement

```
MERGE INTO tablea a 
     using tableb b ON( a.customer_id = b.customer_id ) 
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE SET a.geo_id = b.geo_id
```

OR a Correlated update

```
update tablea a set 
    a.geo_id = (select geo_id from 
                      tableb b 
                      where a.customer_id = b.customer_id)
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7f5f802c9d016f5122df2cced6e7a58f)

Comment: thank you but result is "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: @MohammadAminKaviani : You have to use proper keys that uniquely identify records. It seems the only `customer_id` condition is not unique